# Installed new ceiling rose. Blew light

Tags: ceiling, light

I've just moved into a 1970s house. When I went to rewire the ceiling lights to I install a “rose” one of the lights came on fine. The other (which has another switch) made a pop noise and the light never came on. I was hoping for advice because I cannot afford an electrician. It's worth mentioning that one fixture was simple and the other looked different and without tape!

[image]

Comment: Did you happen to take a photo of the problem one before rewiring it? If so, please [edit] the question to add it. Either way, please add a photo of the wiring as it is now, and add a tag for your country.

Comment: Proper wiring does not include tape.  That statement is concerning.  Please show a pic of the problem wiring.

Comment: Where was the pop noise?  It can be as simple as the bulb burned out at the same time to a mistake in wiring that caused a short and tripped the breaker.

Comment: I'm sorry that it's so vague. I am a complete novice. We have 2 lights wired in the ceiling. The 1st ceiling light was straight forward. The other light had the wire set up shown in the photo. The red wire was closed in a loop. One green and 2  black wires exposed. I was rewiring this into a ceiling rose. Hope this makes sense

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't make much sense at all. What does "the red wire was closed in a loop" mean? If you don't have any "before" pics, your best bet would be to put the wiring back (to the best of your ability) to the way it was (based on your memory), then take a picture for us. Do _not_ turn the power back on until someone can assess what changes should be made from there.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I don't know how else to explain it

Comment: Means it was done by an electrician. That's a single cable with its outer jacket stripped off and a splice done. *waow*. - A problem I used to have as a novice was not insuring the wires were back into the (metal) box correctly before I put the (metal) cover back, and would get cut by screwing it down. Connections would be fine, except it'd be grounded out somewhere = *pop*. - I'm not familiar with those connectors. Can they even be inserted backwards?

Comment: I've just moved into a 1970s house *in the UK* ... because where's you neutral wire?

Comment: All sorted and working great! Rang my brother in law and he was able to work it out. Thanks